# Does Android set Pivot method works?

Tags: android, pivot, rotateanimation

I have two `ImageViews` one of them located on top of another and both inside a `frameLayout`. As far as I know whatever we add in `frameLayout` will sit on the left top part of screen and we can set their position by setting a `padding` for them, So I've set `paddings` for both of `ImageViews`.

```
upperImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        upperImage.setPadding(250,250, 250, 0);

lowerImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        lowerImage.setPadding(250, 361, 250, 0);    //250+Height of Image
```

I want to rotate my `ImageViews` and I'm almost done with that. the only thing I still haven't done is the location of pivot.

I want to set the pivot point on the center bottom of my `ImageViews`. I've tried many numbers but I didn't get the answer and didn't even find out how that method works. I mean I don't know what's the number it gets as an argument. Is that `pixels` or what?(I call the method for animations in `onCreate` method so I can't use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods so I enter the numbers that these methods return myself.)

I have even tried different places to set pivot point in `java` and even `XML layout`. But that didn't make any changes.

All I want to know is how to set the pivot point at center bottom of my `ImageView` using `setPivot` methods?(They don't seem to be working methods) Can it be the problem with setting the point in `onCreate` method? If yes how can I make it work in `onCreate`?

Comment: you been stuck on this for a bit, nobody posted on your question so instead of it being lost in the abyss of questions i made it with the custom view how i was telling you before, you can tweak it up to whatever specifications youd like :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember to put the actual graphic in the res folders for your bitmap and change the name in the constructor or whatever when it loads the bitmap

PivotView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class PivotView extends View{
    public Bitmap arm;
    public Bitmap hand;
    public int armrotation = 0;
    public int handrotation = 0;
public PivotView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        arm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.arm );
        hand = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.hand );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
        canvas.rotate((float)armrotation, 0, (float)canvas.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(arm, new Rect(0,0,arm.getWidth(),arm.getHeight()), new Rect(0,
                canvas.getHeight()*1/3,canvas.getWidth()*1/5,canvas.getHeight()), null);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        matrix.setRectToRect(new RectF(0,0,(float)hand.getWidth(),(float)hand.getHeight()), new RectF(0,
                (float)canvas.getHeight()*1/4,(float)canvas.getWidth()*1/5,(float)canvas.getHeight()*4/10), Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);

        matrix.preRotate((float)handrotation,(float)hand.getWidth()/2,(float)hand.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(hand, matrix, null);


    }
    public void rotatArm(int rotate){
        Log.d("arm", String.valueOf(rotate));
        armrotation = rotate;

    }
    public void rotateHand(int rotate){
        Log.d("hand", String.valueOf(rotate));
        handrotation = rotate;

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

    public SeekBar hand;
    public SeekBar arm;
    public PivotView robot;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        hand = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekhand);
        hand.setMax(360);
        arm = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekarm);
        arm.setMax(90);
        robot = (PivotView)findViewById(R.id.pivot);
        hand.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        arm.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(seekBar.getId()){
        case R.id.seekarm:
            rotatethearm(progress);
            //robot.invalidate();
            break;
        case R.id.seekhand:
            rotatethehand(progress);
            //robot.invalidate();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void rotatethearm(int progress){
        robot.rotatArm(progress);
        robot.invalidate();

    }
    public void rotatethehand(int progress){
        robot.rotateHand(progress);
        robot.invalidate();
    }

}
```

Make your layout like so with custom view, remember to use your package name in place where it says com.example.pivotview in the layout for the custom view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<com.example.pivotview.PivotView
    android:id="@+id/pivot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.example.pivotview.PivotView>

   <SeekBar 
       android:id="@+id/seekarm"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
       android:layout_width = "match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <SeekBar
       android:id="@+id/seekhand"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/seekarm"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```